# angularjs factory shows unreachable code error in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am setting up an angular application which has a factory to post data to the server

```js
angular.module('new-ticket-app')
.factory('CreateTicketFactory', function($http, $rootScope){
    var CreateTicketFactory = {
        async: function($params) {
            return $http({
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','X-Auth-Token': $rootScope.access_token},
                url: $rootScope.resourceurl+'/server',
                method: "POST",
                data: $params,
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return response.data;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return CreateTicketFactory;
});
```

the controller code is

```js
CreateTicketFactory.async($params).then(
    function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    },
    function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    }
);
```

the above code shows **unreachable code** error in firefox and it does not work properly when the application is loaded for the first time.

Comment: WHERE does it show this error?

Comment: /*Return the promise to the controller*/
      return promise ; on line 18

Comment: What is this promise variable?

Comment: @AdamGoldman it is returning a promise value to the function async

Comment: Where is it being declared? where is the value being assigned to this variable?

Comment: `return promise;` is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

You have three `return`'s in one function. The `return $http` line will always return before your `return promise` line, therefore it is unreachable code. If you want to return the promise that the $http call itself returns then just do `return $http({... parameters })` without the `.then` and without the `return promise` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a
>   configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and
>   **returns a promise**.

In other words you are trying to return a promise after a promise already has been returned which is unreachable code.

Either you handle the promise on the place you call it **or** you supply, next to the data parameters, a callback that will executed as soon as the promise resolves.